# Java HW Help. Loops with user input for even number values

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

I have to write a main program that asks the user for a number between 10 and 20 and its prints the even numbers between that number and 50. If the number is not in the 10 and 20 range, inclusive, the program will keep prompting the user for a valid number.

So far this is what I have

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please choose a number between 10 and 20!  ");
        int number = keyboard.nextInt();
        int newnumber = number;

        while (number <= 10 || number >= 20) {
            System.out.print("No, between 10 and 20: ");
            System.out.println("Please choose a number between 10 and 20!  ");
            number = keyboard.nextInt();

        }
        while (number >= 10 || number <= 20) {
            int limit = 50;
            for (int i= 10; newnumber <= 50; i++) {
                if (i% 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(newnumber);
                    newnumber=newnumber+2;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: my code isn't giving me the even numbers if the user inputs a odd number

Comment: Replace everything after the first `while` loop with this: `IntStream.rangeClosed(number, 50).filter(n -> n%2 == 0).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to your problem, but your first while loop will prevent the user from putting in 10 or 20 because the while loop keeps checking if the input is equal to those two.

Your second while loop isn't doing much and would make more sense as an if statement - If you hadn't already verified that it was in the range in your first while loop.

Now your actual problem is you start your counter as `i` but increment `newnumber`.  Even if you were incrementing `i`, it would still never work for odds because your starting number is odd and you increment by 2.  Your two options are to

- start i at number, unless number is odd then number+1
- increment the loop counter by 1 each iteration

Using the first option

```
while (number < 10 || number > 20) {
    System.out.print("No, between 10 and 20: ");
    System.out.println("Please choose a number between 10 and 20!  ");
    number = keyboard.nextInt();
}

for (int i = (number % 2 == 0 ? number : number+1); i <= 50; i+=2) {
    System.out.println(newnumber);
}
```

Notice that I quit checking if each iteration was even because I made sure to start with an even number and increment by 2.